# Convert long data frame into wide data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape2

I am trying to convert long data form into wide data form in R. 
For instance, I have following data frame:

```
a = rep(c("A","B","C","D"),4)
b = rep(c("COL1","COL2","COL3","COL4"),4)
val = 101:116
df = as.data.frame(cbind(a,b,val))
df
```

I would like to see the result as:

```
row <- as.list(levels(df$a))
col <- as.list(levels(df$b))

test <- data.frame()

i = 1

  for (j in 1:4) {
    for(k in 1:4){
      test[j,k]  =   df$val[i]
      i = i + 1 
    }
  }

colnames(test) <- c("COL1","COL2","COL3","COL4")
rownames(test) <- c("A","B","C","D")
test
```

Would appreciate if you could suggest an elegant solution using some handy function.
Thanks,
Qasim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your id columns where really unique, you could use reshape

```
reshape(data=df, direction = "wide", idvar = "a", timevar = "b", v.names = "val")
```

But as they are not unique, the following will get you on your way.

```
df$fakeid <- rep(1:4, each=4)
reshape(data=df, direction = "wide", idvar = "fakeid", drop = "a", timevar = "b", v.names = "val")
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `unstack`:

```
df.out <- unstack(df, val ~ b)
rownames(df.out) <- unique(df$a)
```

Using `reshape2`, it requires a bit of a trick to get an `id` column, because your identifiers do not *uniquely* identify the values.

```
dcast(transform(df, id=rep(1:4, each=4)), id ~ b, value.var="val")
```

you can then add the row names similarly.