# Dataframe merge rows

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe in R

```
my_df <- data.frame(V1 = c(1,2,3,1), V2 = c("A","B","C","A"), V3 = c("S1", "S1", "S1", "S2"), V4 = c("x","x","x","x"), V5 = c("y","y","y","y"), V6 =c("A", "B", "C", "D"))

> my_df
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
1  1  A S1  x  y  A
2  2  B S1  x  y  B
3  3  C S1  x  y  C
4  1  A S2  x  y  D
```

Now I want to check if the combination of values in V1 and V2, occurs multiple times in the df. In my example my_df lines 1 and 4 have the same values '1 A' and '1 A'. If this happens, I want the following output:

```
> my_df_new
  V1 V2    V3 V4 V5  V6_S1   V6_S2
1  1  A S1;S2  x  y      A       D
2  2  B    S1  x  y      B     
3  3  C    S1  x  y      C
```

So basically two things have changed:

- V3 now contains the values of all the lines in the df in which the values in V1 and V2 are the same. They are seperated by a ';'
- there are new V6 columns that contains the original values of this column.

The rest of the columns and values should stay the same.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert long data frame into wide data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16143441/convert-long-data-frame-into-wide-data-frame)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way using `dplyr`, `group_by` `V1` and `V2`, collapse `V3`, create a new column (`V7`) to `spread` repeated values.

```
library(dplyr)

my_df %>%
  group_by(V1, V2) %>%
  mutate(V3 = toString(V3), 
         V7 = paste0("V6_S", row_number())) %>%
  tidyr::spread(V7, V6)

#     V1 V2    V3     V4    V5  V6_S1 V6_S2
#  <dbl> <fct> <chr> <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct>
#1     1 A     S1, S2 x     y     A     D    
#2     2 B     S1     x     y     B     NA   
#3     3 C     S1     x     y     C     NA
```

Comment: How can you apply this to a list of dataframes?

Comment: @user1987607 Just use `lapply` or `map` to loop over each dataframe in the list and apply the same function to all.

Comment: I don't understand what row_number() is doing here. Why not use the values from V3 to give the name to this column: S1 and S2

Comment: ahh..yes. It didn't occur to me that I can use it that way. Yes, you can do `my_df %>%
  group_by(V1, V2) %>%
  mutate(V7 = paste0("V6_", V3), 
         V3 = toString(V3)) %>%
  tidyr::spread(V7, V6)`

Comment: your commands work fine with the test dataframe. However with my real dataframe, it's not behaving as expected. So I'll have to investigate further.

Comment: I think I found why it's not working with my real dataset. In my example I only had one 'V6' column with values that needed to be spread. However, in my actual dataset I have three (V6, V9 and V10). The all need to have new columns (V6_S1, V6_S2, V9_S1, V9_S2, V10_S1 and V10_S2). Do I need to repeat then the lines 'mutate' & 'spread'? Or is this not possible?

Comment: For that I guess you need to `gather` those columns and bring them in one column and then follow `group_by ....` etc.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a more concise way to doing this that doesn't force staff, but this is what I came up with,

```
library(data.table)
library(splitstackshape)

cSplit(setDT(my_df)[, .(V3 = toString(V3), 
                        V4 = V4[1], 
                        V5 = V5[1], 
                        V6 = toString(V6)), .(V1, V2)], 'V6')

#   V1 V2     V3 V4 V5 V6_1 V6_2
#1:  1  A S1, S2  x  y    A    D
#2:  2  B     S1  x  y    B <NA>
#3:  3  C     S1  x  y    C <NA>
```